# Generate Tables in R mark down

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

How can I write the codes to create the following table in Mark Down?
I don't know how to generate the first row

I know the very simple case

| Header 1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Content | Content |

[image]

Comment: R frames themselves do not work with header row "groups", as you're showing there. Look into `kableExtra`, `gt`, and other report-generating packages. Note that you can render a report to look nice like this, but the result it not a "frame" that R will know how to continue to work with. Rendering like this should be the last step in a workflow.

Comment: `flextable` and `ftExtra` provide another possible solution.